# snprintf is not working correct for special chars

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

I am trying to create a variable with using ***snprintf*** formatter but when I use some special chars inside string such as "!", I am getting this wrong value:

"Hi there, this is esp32!" => "⸮⸮?"

[image]

```
void sendMessage(String _channelName, String _username, String _messageText, String _messageType) {
  Serial.println(_messageText); // writes correct => "Hi there, this is esp32!"
  char messageData[500];
  snprintf(messageData, sizeof(messageData),
           "[\"SEND\\ndestination:/app/chat/%s\\n\\n{\\\"username\\\":\\\"%s\\\",\\\"message\\\":\\\"%s\\\",\\\"messageType\\\":\\\"%s\\\"}\\u0000\"]",
           _channelName,
           _username,
           _messageText, // writes wrong => "⸮⸮?\"
           _messageType);
  String messageDataConverted = String(messageData);
  Serial.println(messageDataConverted);
  webSocket.sendTXT(messageDataConverted);
}
```

Comment: my guess is that _username contains junk

Comment: Sorry but I couldn't understand. ```_messageText = Hi there, this is esp32! ``` , but it is writing "⸮⸮?\" after use snprintf

Comment: What is `String`? What is `Serial`? Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem. If these objects belong to a platform-specific API, then please specify which platform that is.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel this is Arduino and it's coding with c/c++. But the problem is in snprintf. Serial.println() is similar with printf();

Comment: note that the junk is after 'username:' not 'message:' hence my comment about junk in _username

Comment: @gurka Also, are you writing C or C++? They are different though related languages.

Comment: @gurkan: Since you have now mentioned that your question applies to a specific platform (arduino), I have added an appropriate tag to your question. However, I have the impression that it may also be appropriate to remove the `c` and `c++` tags and replace it with the [`arduino-c++`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/arduino-c%2b%2b/info) tag. I did not do this myself, though, because I am not familiar with arduino. After reading the linked tag description, you should be able to judge which tag is appropriate.

Comment: @gurkan In Arduino, you use C++. I'm not sure why you have the C tag here.

Comment: One thing you must know about `printf` and family is it will accept any arguments and if they do not match the types accepted by format arguments, you're probably on your own. The program will trust you and will happily try to use an integer as a float or a null-terminated string. Some implementations will match the format arguments with the arguments given  and issue a warning if they don't match, but they types must match. If you get a warning praise your preferred deity and don't ignore the warning.

Comment: Perhaps use `swprintf()`?

Comment: I'm guessing that Arduino and the standard C libraries that underlay it only handle ASCII characters, and your string is UTF-8 or UTF-16. https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdio.html#ga77070c245d4ca4f7ec7d7144260fb875

Comment: I would insist on what @AndreasWenzel already mentioned: What is `String`? Are you sure that the `printf()` formatter `%s` supports `String`? Per standard, for `%s` an argument of type `char*` (or `const char*`) has to be provided.

Answer (score 1):

The function prototype of `snprintf()` looks like this:

```
int snprintf ( char * s, size_t n, const char * format, ... );
```

`snprintft()` doesn't expecting an Arduino `String` which is the type of your `_username`. You need to convert it from a `String` to a `char *` with `_username.c_str()`.

Comment: BTW, you should use `Arduino-C++` instead of generic `C++` tag for your Arduino question, otherwise you will get all kind of comments from people who know C++ but not necessary know the nuances of Arduino related data object such as `String`.